# Atomic physics: Decomposition of many-electron Hilbert space into terms

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, many-body

Suppose that $\mathcal H$ is the Hilbert space of $N$-electron states where each electron is in some atomic orbital with given $n$ and $l$. (For example, $\mathcal H$ could be the Hilbert space of $2$-electron states where each electron is in a $2p$ atomic orbital; this example arises naturally in the carbon atom.)

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_symbol#Term_symbols_for_an_electron_configuration), the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ decomposes into a *direct sum of terms*.

No proof is given. It's possible that I have misinterpreted the intent of the calculation in the Wikipedia article. (Indeed, the phrase "direct sum decomposition" is not explicitly used in the article.) However, I've seen the same claim being made in inorganic chemistry textbooks such as Shriver & Atkins or Miessler where this kind of physics gets applied, so I'm fairly confident that my interpretation is correct.

I would be grateful if you could help me understand why it is that $\mathcal H$ decomposes as a direct sum of terms.

---

**Definitions.** Assuming that I've understood the concepts correctly, the relevant definitions are as follows.

- A **level** with orbital, spin and total angular momentum eigenvalues $L, S, J$ is a $(2J + 1)$-dimensional subspace of $\mathcal H$, spanned by a basis of states with eigenvalues $L, S, J$ and $J_z = -J, -J+1, \cdots, J-1, J$. These basis states must be related to one another via the $J_\pm$ raising and lowering operators.
- A **term** with orbital and spin angular momentum eigenvalues $L$ and $S$ is a $(2L + 1)(2S + 1)$-dimensional subspace of $\mathcal H$, which is itself a direct sum of levels with eigenvalues $L, S$ and $J = |L - S|, |L - S| + 1, \cdots, L + S - 1, L + S$. **Correction:** (see comment after jd27's answer) This $(2L + 1)(2S + 1)$-dimensional subspace must be a *tensor product* of a orbital angular momentum multiplet with eigenvalue $L$ with a spin angular momentum multiplet with eigenvalue $S$.

**Antisymmetry under particle exchange.** It is important to bear in mind that every state in $\mathcal H$ must be antisymmetric under particle exchange, since electrons are fermions.

**Decomposing $\mathcal H$ into levels.** I think I understand why the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ should decompose as a direct sum of levels.

- If I'm not mistaken, $L, S, J$ and $J_z$ are a set of commuting operators. So there exists a basis for  $\mathcal H$ consisting of states that are simultaneously eigenstates of $L, S, J$ and $J_z$.
- Given a state with eigenvalues $L, S, J$ and $J_z$, we can construct other states with the same $L, S$ and $J$ eigenvalues but different $J_z$ eigenvalues by applying the raising and lowering operators $J_+$ and $J_-$. Together, these states form a level.

Note that, in order for this argument to work, it's important that acting on a state with the $J_+$ and $J_-$ operators preserves the property of being antisymmetric under particle exchange. Indeed, this is the case.

**Decomposing $\mathcal H$ into terms.** I find it very surprising that the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ decomposes as a direct sum of terms. I can't think any reason (intuitive or rigorous) that would suggest that this is the case.

Indeed, suppose that $\mathcal H$ contains a level with eigenvalues $L = 3, S = 1, J = 4$. Assuming that $\mathcal H$ decomposes as a direct sum of terms, then our $L = 3, S = 1, J = 4$ level must be part of a $L = 3, S = 1$ term. This would imply that $\mathcal H$ also contains a $L = 3, S = 1, J = 3$ level and a $L = 3, S = 1, J = 2$ level. But as far as I can see, there is no symmetry operation that maps a $L = 3, S = 1, J = 4$ level into a $L = 3, S = 1, J = 3$ level or a $L = 3, S = 1, J = 2$ level!

An idea for a proof strategy is to use Clebsch-Gordan style addition of angular momenta. As a warmup exercise,
let us ignore the constraint that states must be antisymmetric under particle exchange. Using addition of angular momenta, we can decompose the orbital component of the Hilbert space into a direct sum of multiplets with various different orbital angular momentum eigenvalues $L$. Similarly, we can decompose the spin component of the Hilbert space into a direct sum of multiplets with various different spin angular momentum eigenvalues $S$. Tensoring together any one of our orbital multiplets (which has orbital angular momentum $L$, say) with any one of our spin multiplets (which has spin $S$, say), we can apply addition of angular momenta once more to express this tensor product as a direct sum of total angular momentum multiplets with $J = |L - S|, \cdots, L + S$. This is a term! But there is a problem: as it stands, our whole calculation fails to take into account the requirement that the states must be antisymmetric under particle exchange. I can't see a way around this.

So can you please help me understand why $\mathcal H$ decomposes as a direct sum of terms? For my purposes, the most helpful answer would provide some intuition based on symmetry arguments, as well as a link to a rigorous mathematical proof.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_representations#Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_theory). The topic is also treated in most qm books like Sakurai for example under the name "addition of angular momentum".

Comment: Also where exactly does the linked wikipedia article say that "the Hilbert space H
 decomposes into a direct sum of terms."? The linked wikipedia article doesnt even contain the phrase direct sum.

Comment: @jd27 I think that it's more complicated than just angular momentum coupling, because the wave function also has to be antisymmetric under particle label exchange. In other words, the Hilbert space is the space of all $N$-particle, anti-symmetric, coupled spatial-spin electronic states. Building term symbols via L-S coupling does this systematically, and it's not *just* about angular-momentum coupling. All that said, I don't know how to prove that building term symbols generates all possible relevant states.

Comment: @march anti-symmetrization just restricts to certain irreducible representations based on their symmetry. That said, i dont really know much about chemistry, so there might be more to it.

Comment: @jd27 The wikipedia article doesn't _explicitly_ say that $H$ decomposes into a direct sum of terms. However, the worked example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_symbol#Term_symbols_for_an_electron_configuration) for the carbon atom is precisely that - an attempt at decomposing $H$ into a direct sum of terms.

Comment: The anti-symmetrization due to the electron having to obey Fermi statistics is _precisely_ what causes me the trouble. If it wasn't for the anti-symmetrization, I'd have no problem proving that $H$ decomposes as a direct sum of terms. I'll update my post to make this clear.

Comment: If you can formulate the statement "anti-symmetrization restricts to certain irreducible representations based on their symmetry" in a more precise way, I might be able to figure out the rest myself.

Comment: @KennyWong See for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1831086/symmetric-decompositions-of-su2-representations) post on math stackexchange. Maybe i will look into it more tomorrow.

Comment: @jd27 Thanks for sharing that post from math.SE. If I don't get an answer here on physics.SE, maybe I'll ask a question on math.SE, framing this problem in purely mathematical language along the lines of that post you shared.

Comment: @march I think I've figured this out - see my self-posted answer below. I'd be grateful for feedback/corrections, though there is of course no obligation.

Answer (score 3):

Now that I have internalised @jd27's ideas, I believe the answer is devastatingly simple.

As a warmup exercise, let's consider the Hilbert space $\mathcal H^{\text{dist}}$ consisting of states of $N$ *distinguishable* particles, where each particle has quantum numbers $n$, $l$ and $s$. $\mathcal H^{\text{dist}}$ is similar to the $N$-electron Hilbert space described in my original post, except that we do *not* impose the Fermi-Dirac requirement that states must be antisymmetric under particle exchange.

There are three relevant symmetry groups acting on $\mathcal H^{\text{dist}}$:

- $SO(3)_{\text{orbital}}$, the Lie group of $3$-dimensional spatial rotations, whose infinitesimal generators are $L_x, L_y$ and $L_z$. (The $L_x, L_y$ and $L_z$ operators denote the *sum* of the orbital angular momenta of *all* $N$ particles.)
- $SU(2)_{\text{spin}}$, the Lie group associated with spin, whose infinitesimal generators are $S_x, S_y$ and $S_z$. (The $S_x, S_y$ and $S_z$ operators denote the *sum* of the spins of *all* $N$ particles.)
- $\text{Sym}(N)$, the permutation group on the labels of the $N$ particles.

Crucially, all three of these symmetry groups commute with one another. Therefore, the overall symmetry group is a direct product, $G = SO(3)_{\text{orbital}} \times SU(2)_{\text{spin}} \times \text{Sym}(N)$.

It is a general fact that every irreducible representation of a direct product is isomorphic to a tensor product of representations of the factors of the direct product. For us, this means that every irreducible representation of $G$ is a isomorphic to a tensor product of the form $$U_L \otimes V_S \otimes W_{\Gamma},$$
where

- $U_L$ is the $(2L + 1)$-dimensional irreducible representation of $SO(3)_{\text{orbital}}$ with orbital quantum number $L$;
- $V_S$ is the $(2S + 1)$-dimensional irreducible representation of $SU(2)_{\text{spin}}$ with spin quantum number $S$;
- $W_{\Gamma}$ is some irreducible representation of $\text{Sym}(N)$, which we label as $\Gamma$.

Our Hilbert space $\mathcal H^{\text {dist}}$, when viewed as a representation of $G$, is isomorphic to a direct sum of these irreducible representations. In other words,
$$\mathcal H^{\text {dist}} \cong \oplus_{L \in \mathbb N, \ \  S \in \tfrac 1 2 \mathbb N, \ \ \Gamma \in \{ \text{irreps of } \text{Sym}(N)\} } \ n_{L, S, \Gamma} \cdot  U_L \otimes V_S \otimes W_{\Gamma} \qquad \qquad (\star)$$
where each $n_{L, S, \Gamma}$ is a non-negative integer, specifying the multiplicity of the irreducible representation $U_L \otimes V_S \otimes W_{\Gamma}$ in $\mathcal H^{\text {dist}}$.

However, $\mathcal H^{\text {dist}}$ is a Hilbert space of $N$ *distinguishable* particles. This is not what we're interested in. We're actually interested in the Hilbert space $\mathcal H^{\text {FD}}$ of $N$ *indistinguishable fermions*, which obey Fermi-Dirac statistics. By definition, $\mathcal H^{\text {FD}}$ is the subspace of $\mathcal H^{\text {dist}}$ consisting of the states in $\mathcal H^{\text {dist}}$ that are antisymmetric under particle exchange.

Fortunately, once we have decomposed $\mathcal H^{\text {dist}}$ into irreps of $G$, it is easy to figure out how $\mathcal H^{\text {FD}}$ decomposes into irreps of $G$.

Amongst the irreducible representations of $\text{Sym}(N)$, there is one that is particularly relevant: the *alternating* representation $\Gamma_{\text{Alt}}$. The alternating representation $\Gamma_{\text{Alt}}$ is the one-dimensional representation of $\text{Sym}(N)$, where an element in $\text{Sym}(N)$ is mapped to $+1$ if it is an even permutation, or $-1$ if it is an odd permutation.

If $\mathcal H^{\text {dist}}$ decomposes into irreps of $G$ according to equation $(\star)$, then $\mathcal H^{\text FD}$ decomposes into irreps of $G$ in the following manner.
$$\mathcal H^{\text FD} \cong \oplus_{L \in \mathbb N, \ \  S \in \tfrac 1 2 \mathbb N } \ n_{L, S, \Gamma = \Gamma_{\text Alt}} \cdot  U_L \otimes V_S \otimes W_{\Gamma = \Gamma_{\text {Alt}}}$$
In other words, the irreps appearing in the decomposition of $\mathcal H^{\text {FD}} $ are precisely those irreps in the decomposition of $\mathcal H^{\text {dist}}$ where $\Gamma$ is the alternating representation $\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}$ of $\text{Sym}(N)$.

Presumably, each copy of $U_L \otimes V_S \otimes W_{\Gamma = \Gamma_{\text {Alt}}}$ in this direct sum is called a *term*. Thus we have succeeded in proving that $\mathcal H^{\text {dist}}$ decomposes as a direct sum of terms.

**Example: the carbon atom.** To make this more concrete, let's work through the details in the case of the carbon atom. This is the example in the Wikipedia article that I quoted. Much of this example has already been fleshed out by @jd27.

First, let's describe $\mathcal H^{\text {dist}}$, the Hilbert space of $2$ *distinguishable* particles where each particle has quantum numbers $n = 2$, $l = 1$ and $s = \tfrac 1 2$. Using the usual addition-of-angular-momenta machinery, we find that
\begin{align} \mathcal H^{\text {dist}} \cong \ \ & (U_{L = 2} \otimes V_{S = 1} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}}) \oplus (U_{L = 1} \otimes V_{S = 1} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}}) \oplus (U_{L = 0} \otimes V_{S = 1} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}}) \oplus \\ & (U_{L = 2} \otimes V_{S = 0} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}}) \oplus (U_{L = 1} \otimes V_{S = 0} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}})  \oplus (U_{L = 0} \otimes V_{S = 0} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}}). \end{align}
Here, $\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}$ is the one-dimensional trivial representation of $\text{Sym}(2)$ that maps all elements of $\text{Sym}(2)$ to $+1$, while, as before, $\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}$ is the one-dimensional alternating representation.

So $\mathcal H^{\text {FD}}$, the subspace of $\mathcal H^{\text {dist}}$ satisfying Fermi-Dirac statistics, has the following decomposition.
$$\mathcal H^{\text {FD}} \cong  (U_{L = 1} \otimes V_{S = 1} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}}) \oplus (U_{L = 2} \otimes V_{S = 0} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}}) \oplus (U_{L = 0} \otimes V_{S = 0} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}}). $$
Each summand in this direct sum is a term.

Note that when you get to $3$ electrons and beyond, the representation theory becomes more complicated, because when $N\geq 3$, $\text{Sym}(N)$ has more irreps than just the trivial rep and the alternating rep. But the overall idea remains the same.

---

**Decomposing into orbital and spin degrees of freedom**

When computing these decompositions by hand, dealing with $\mathcal H^{\text{dist}}$ directly can be overwhelming. It may be more practical to decompose the orbital and spin degrees of freedom separately, before combining everything together at the end.

Let's work through this. The Hilbert space $\mathcal H^{\text{dist}}$ can be thought of as a tensor product,
$$ \mathcal H^{\text{dist}} \cong \mathcal H^{\text{dist, orbital}} \otimes \mathcal H^{\text{dist, spin}},  $$
where

- $\mathcal H^{\text{dist, orbital}}$ is the $(2l+1)^N$-dimensional Hilbert space of orbital degrees of freedom;
- $\mathcal H^{\text{dist, spin}}$ is the $(2s + 1)^N$-dimensional Hilbert space of spin degrees of freedom.

As it stands, the $\cong$ symbol denotes a *vector space* isomorphism.

But there is more to it. Notice that the group $SO(3)_{\text{orbital}} \times \text{Sym}(N)$ acts on $\mathcal H^{\text{dist, orbital}}$. So $\mathcal H^{\text{dist, orbital}}$ is a representation of $SO(3)_{\text{orbital}}  \times \text{Sym}(N)$. Equivalently, we can say that $\mathcal H^{\text{dist, orbital}}$ is a representation of $G = SO(3)_{\text{orbital}} \times SU(2)_{\text{spin}} \times \text{Sym}(N)$, with the $SU(2)_{\text{spin}}$ factor acting trivially.

Similarly, $\mathcal H^{\text{dist, spin}}$ is also representation of $G$, except that this time, it is the $SO(3)_{\text{orbital}}$ factor that acts trivially.

Now if you think about how $\text{Sym}(N)$ acts on $\mathcal H^{\text{dist, orbital}}$ and $\mathcal H^{\text{dist, spin}}$, and if you refresh your memory of how a tensor product representation is defined, you will quickly realise that the equation
$$ \mathcal H^{\text{dist}} \cong \mathcal H^{\text{dist, orbital}} \otimes \mathcal H^{\text{dist, spin}}$$
is valid not only as an isomorphism of vector spaces, but also as an isomorphism of $G$-representations!

This observation is very handy for practical calculations.

**Example: the carbon atom (revisited).** For the carbon atom, a Clebsch-Gordan style additional of angular momenta calculation gives
$$ \mathcal H^{\text{dist, orbital}} \cong (U_{L = 2} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}}) \oplus (U_{L = 1} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}}) \oplus (U_{L = 0} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}})$$
and
$$ \mathcal H^{\text{dist, spin}} \cong (V_{S = 1} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}}) \oplus (V_{S = 0} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}}).$$

To obtain a decomposition for $\mathcal H^{\text{dist}}$, all we have to do is tensor together our decompositions for $\mathcal H^{\text{dist, orbital}}$ and $\mathcal H^{\text{dist, spin}}$. Using the identities
\begin{align}W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}} & \cong W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}} \\
 W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}} & \cong W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}} \\
W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}} & \cong W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}},\end{align}
we can evaluate this tensor product, and we obtain the same decomposition for $\mathcal H^{\text{dist}}$ that we got earlier.

**Example: the nitrogen atom.** Here, life gets more interesting because we have $N = 3$ particles (still with quantum numbers $n = 2$, $l = 1$ and $s = \tfrac 1 2$).

The reason why life gets more interesting is that the $\text{Sym}(3)$ group has *three* irreducible representations:

- $\Gamma_{\text{Triv}}$, the one-dimensional trivial representation
- $\Gamma_{\text{Alt}}$,  the one-dimensional alternating representation
- $\Gamma_{\text{Stand}}$,  the two-dimensional standard representation, which arises from viewing the elements of  $\text{Sym}(3)$ as $2 \times 2$ matrices implementing the geometric symmetries of a triangle.

We have
\begin{align*} \mathcal H^{\text{dist, orbital}} \cong & \ \ (U_{L = 3} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}}) \oplus (U_{L = 2} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Stand}}}) \oplus \\ & \ \ \ \ (U_{L = 1} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}}) \oplus  (U_{L = 1} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Stand}}}) \oplus (U_{L = 0} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}})  \end{align*}
and
$$ \mathcal H^{\text{dist, spin}} \cong (V_{S = 3/2} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}}) \oplus (V_{S = 1/2} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Stand}}}).$$

To take the tensor product of these two decompositions, we can make use of the identities
\begin{align}W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}} & \cong W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}} \\
 W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}} & \cong W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}} \\
W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}} & \cong W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}} \\
W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Stand}}} & \cong W_{\Gamma_{\text {Stand}}} \\
W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Stand}}} & \cong W_{\Gamma_{\text {Stand}}} \\
W_{\Gamma_{\text {Stand}}} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Stand}}} & \cong W_{\Gamma_{\text {Triv}}} \oplus W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}} \oplus W_{\Gamma_{\text {Stand}}}
\end{align}
which I read off from the character table for $\text{Sym}(3)$. This gives us a decomposition of $\mathcal H^{\text{dist}}$ into irreps of $G$. $\mathcal H^{\text{FD}}$, the subspace of $\mathcal H^{\text{dist}}$  containing the states obeying the Fermi-Dirac antisymmetry condition, is the direct sum of all irreps where $\Gamma = \Gamma_{\text{Alt}}$.

Once the dust settles, we obtain the result
$$\mathcal H^{\text{FD}} \cong (U_{L = 2} \otimes V_{S = 1/2} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}}) \oplus (U_{L = 1} \otimes V_{S = 1/2} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}}) \oplus (U_{L = 0} \otimes V_{S = 3/2} \otimes W_{\Gamma_{\text {Alt}}}),$$
in agreement with the Wikipedia article.

---

**Working directly with $\mathcal H^{\text{FD}}$**

So far, we have described how to analyse the representation theory for $\mathcal H^{\text{FD}}$, the Hilbert space of $N$ *distinguishable* particles, before extracting the representation theory for $\mathcal H^{\text{FD}}$, the subspace of states that are antisymmetric under particle exchange.

I have done things this way because the issues that we addressed during this journey were the issues that were giving me grief when I originally asked my question on this website. It's good to be able to think clearly about these issues.

However, if you simply want to prove that $\mathcal H^{\text{FD}}$ decomposes as a direct sum of terms, then there is a much quicker way to get there.

Indeed, the group $\text{Sym}(N)$ acts on $\mathcal H^{\text{dist}}$. Viewing $\mathcal H^{\text{dist}}$ as a representation of $\text{Sym}(N)$, $\mathcal H^{\text{dist}}$  has a decomposition of the form
$$ \mathcal H^{\text{dist}} \cong \oplus_{\Gamma \in \{ \text{irreps of } \text{Sym}(N) \}} \ n_\Gamma \cdot W_\Gamma. \qquad \qquad (\dagger)$$
(Here, the $\cong$ symbol denotes an isomorphism of $\text{Sym}(N)$ representations.)

The $\mathcal H^{\text{FD}}$ subspace of $\mathcal H^{\text{dist}}$ can be identified as the direct sum of all the summands in $(\dagger)$ that are isomorphic to $W_\Gamma$.

Since the action of  $SO(3)_{\text{orbital}} \times SU(2)_{\text{spin}}$ commutes with the action of the group $\text{Sym}(N)$, it follows that $\mathcal H^{\text{FD}}$ is an *invariant subspace* of $\mathcal H^{\text{dist}}$. That is, the action of $SO(3)_{\text{orbital}} \times SU(2)_{\text{spin}}$ maps elements of $\mathcal H^{\text{FD}}$ to elements of $\mathcal H^{\text{FD}}$.

So $\mathcal H^{\text{FD}}$ can be viewed as a representation of $SO(3)_{\text{orbital}} \times SU(2)_{\text{spin}}$ in its own right! Therefore, $\mathcal H^{\text{FD}}$ be decomposed as a direct sum of irreducible representations of $SO(3)_{\text{orbital}} \times SU(2)_{\text{spin}}$.

Every irrep of $SO(3)_{\text{orbital}} \times SU(2)_{\text{spin}}$ take the form $U_L \otimes V_S$, for some $L \in \mathbb N$ and $S \in \tfrac 1 2 \mathbb N$. Thus, this decomposition of $\mathcal H^{\text{FD}}$ looks like
$$ \mathcal H^{\text{FD}} \cong \oplus_{L \in \mathbb N, \ \  S \in \tfrac 1 2 \mathbb N } \ n_{L, S} \cdot  U_L \otimes V_S.$$
(Here, the $\cong$ symbol denotes an isomorphism of $SO(3)_{\text{orbital}} \times SU(2)_{\text{spin}}$ representations.)

Each $U_L \otimes V_S$ in this decomposition is called a *term*. And that's all there is to it.

Comment: I am not sure about your derivation, it is a little over my head. But i have updated my answer to include a relatively elementary proof in the case of two electrons in the same state (but arbitrary orbital arbitrary angular momentum). I also found a reference which i included in my post.

Comment: I also don't necessarily have the relevant background to evaluate this.  That said, I'm not convinced, for the following reason.  Two particles is special in the world of antisymmetrization of atomic states because you can always find a basis that factorizes between spin and spatial degrees of freedom (i.e., a product of an antisymmetric spin state and symmetric spatial state and vice-versa), but this *can't* be done for more than two particles, in general (if I remember correctly).  This *seems* to imply that that a simple tensor product with the alternating group can't be the whole story.

Comment: @march Indeed, the two particle case is special. The fact that this symmetric/antisymmetric factorization works only for $N = 2$ is a manifestation of the fact that $\text{Sym}(2)$ has only two irreps (the trivial irrep and the alternating irrep), while $\text{Sym}(N)$ for $N \geq 3$ has additional irreps. I appreciate you engaging with this - your comment earlier helped me get my bearings with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer (see edit below for partial answer), instead i focus mostly on describing what i think is meant to happen in the particular example in the wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_symbol#Term_symbols_for_an_electron_configuration).

Consider the electronic configuration $2p^2$ that you have eluded to.
The Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is
$$
\mathcal{H}= \Lambda ( V \otimes V),
$$
where $V = 1 \otimes 1/2$ is the single electron eigenspace and $\Lambda$ is the anti-symmetrization operator.

A basis of $V$ is given by $| m_l m_s \rangle$ with $m_l \in \{ -1,0,1\}$ and $m_s \in \{ +,-\}$. Therefore $V$ is 6 dimensional. $V \otimes V$ is $6*6 =36$ dimensional and the dimension of $\mathcal{H}$ (the anti-symmetric tensor product) is ${6 \choose  2} =15$.

We can label the basis of $\mathcal{H}$ obtained from the basis of $V$ above like this (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_symbol#Term_symbols_for_an_electron_configuration)):

[image: decomposition]

where each row (of the 15 rows) specifies one basis vector of $\mathcal{H}$. For example the first row means that the state $ \Lambda |1,+ \rangle \otimes |0, + \rangle$ is part of the basis.

On the right hand side of the table are the eigenvalues $M_L/ M_S$ of the third component of the total orbital/spin momentum operator applied to the basis state in that row.
Note that all total angular momentum operators commute with $\Lambda$, because they are permutation invariant.
In particular $\Lambda$ commutes with the (total) ladder operators.

Now the highest $M_L$ value is two and the unique state corresponding to it is $\Lambda |1 +\rangle \otimes | 1 - \rangle $, if we apply the total orbital momentum increasing operator to it:
$$
L_{tot,+} \Lambda |1 +\rangle \otimes | 1 - \rangle = \Lambda (L_{+}\otimes I +  I \otimes L_{+} ) |1 +\rangle \otimes | 1 - \rangle =0
$$
and therefore we obtain a 5 dimensional irreducible representation of $so(3)$ by applying the lowering operator $L_{tot,-}$ to this highest weight.
$$
L_{tot,-} \Lambda |1 +\rangle \otimes | 1 - \rangle = \Lambda   (L_{-}\otimes I + I \otimes   L_{-} ) |1 +\rangle \otimes | 1 - \rangle = \Lambda|0 +\rangle \otimes |1 -\rangle +  \Lambda |1 +\rangle \otimes |0 - \rangle    $$
which is a linear combination of two of the vectors in the "one up/one down" part of the table.

Proceeding with the usual decomposition schemes (similar to addition of angular momentum) we (hopefully) arrive at:
$$\mathcal{H}= 2 \otimes 0 \oplus 0 \otimes 0  \oplus 1 \otimes 1  , \tag{1}$$
where the left factor is always an irreducible representation of $so(3)$ induced by the total orbital angular momentum and the right factor induced by the total spin.
The numbers in the above expression are the heighest weights of the representations.

The decomposition makes sense from dimensional considerations since the right hand side has dimension $5+1+9=15$.

The first two summands have definite total total momentum $J=2$ and $J=0$.

For the third summand we use $1\otimes1 = 2 \oplus 1 \oplus 0$ (addition of angular momentum) where on the right the irreps are induced by the total total angular momentum.

Using the spectroscopic term notation the first summand in the above has term ${}^1 D_2$, the second ${}^1 S_0$ and the third has three possibilities for $J$: $ {}^3 P_0,{}^3 P_1 $ and ${}^3 P_2$ in complete agreement with the linked wikipedia article.

In my opinion the decomposition in equation 1 is what is being calculated in the wikipedia article (in step 4) which you have linked to. Is this what you mean by "$\mathcal{H}$ decomposes into a direct sum of terms"?

An idea to prove that such a decomposition always exists may be to consider that the total angular momentum operators commute with $\Lambda$ and therefore the eigenspaces of the total angular momentum operators in $V \otimes V$ and $\Lambda ( V\otimes V)$ are related to each other. Perhaps the decomposition of $V \otimes V$ can be related to the symmetry under $\Lambda$.

### Edit: Proof Of General Formula

After some more thought i have arrived at a general proof of the decomposition for two electrons that are in the same state.

I also found a reference discussing this decomposition (although using the more usual physics basis ket formalism):

- Tanoudji Quantum Mechanics 1-3 Complement BXIV section 2.a (p.1469)

Consider
$$ \Lambda (V \otimes V)$$
with $V = l \otimes 1/2$ for some integer $l$.
The antisymmetrization operator $\Lambda$ is given by
$$ \Lambda = 1/2 (I - T )$$
where $T$ is the transposition operator and $I$ is the identity.

Furthermore we have
$$ T = T^l \otimes T^s,  $$
where $T^l$ acts on $l \otimes l$ by transposition and $T^s$ acts on $1/2 \otimes 1/2$ by transposition.

The total angular momentum operator (and all its related construction like the ladder operators) commutes with $T^l$ from which it follows that all irreducible representations of total angular momentum in $l \otimes l$ are eigenspaces of $T^l$ (with eigenvalue $(-1)^L$ which follows from some Clebsch Gordan argument).
The same reasoning can be applied to the total spin operator (with eigenvalue $(-1)^{S+1}$). Where $L,S$ are the highest weights of the irreducible representations.

From this it follows that for any $w \in L \otimes S$
\begin{align}
\Lambda (w) &= 1/2 (1-T) w = 1/2 ( 1- T^l \otimes T^s) w\\
&=1/2 ( 1- (-1)^L (-1)^{S+1} )w =
\begin{cases}
 w, \quad \text{if} \ L+S  \ \text{is even},\\
0, \quad \text{else}.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Now using the addition of angular momentum rules:
$$
V \otimes V = l \otimes l \otimes 1/2 \otimes 1/2 =(2l \oplus (2l-1) \oplus \cdots \oplus 0)  \otimes (1 \oplus 0).
$$
Therefore using the above formula for $\Lambda$ acting on the products of such irreducible representations:
$$
\Lambda (V \otimes V) =[2l \otimes 0]  \oplus [(2l-1) \otimes 1] \oplus [(2l-2) \otimes 0] \oplus  \cdots \oplus [1 \otimes 1]  \oplus [0 \otimes 0] .
$$
Which is the "even rule" cited in the wikipedia article.

So in the case $l=1$ we arrive at
$\Lambda (V \otimes V) = 2 \otimes 0  \oplus 1 \otimes 1 \oplus 0 \otimes 0$
which is exactly the previously derived formula.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, this is exactly how I interpreted the Wikipedia article. The fact that the total angular momentum operators commute with $\Delta$ may be helpful. I'm still struggling to flesh out the details, but I'll keep digging. Thanks again.

Comment: Your answer has helped me realise that there is a mistake in my original definition of a "term". For a subspace of $\mathcal H$ to be a term, it is essential that this subspace is a tensor product of a $L$-multiplet with an $S$-multiplet. I failed to specify this. (In the carbon atom example, the three terms are the tensor products $2 \otimes 0$, $1 \otimes 1$ and $0 \otimes 0$. By good fortune, all three of these tensor products satisfy the antisymmetry requirement.)

Comment: This $2$-electron example is kind of easy because all the $L$-multiplets and $S$-multiplets are either symmetric or antisymmetric under particle exchnge. The $L = 2$ multiplet is symmetric, the $L = 1$ multiplet is antisymmetric and the $L = 0$ multiplet is symmetric. The $S = 1$ multiplet is symmetric and the $S = 0$ multiplet is antisymmetric. Hence the $2 \otimes 0$, $1 \otimes 1$ and $0 \otimes 0$ tensor products are antisymmetric overall. I wonder how this pattern might generalise for $N$-electron states.

Comment: I think I've managed to finish off your line of thought - see my self-posted answer. There's no pressure to respond, though any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: I understand this argument now, and I believe it's the same as my argument.  Rephrasing your argument for $2$ particles in my notation, we have  $\mathcal H^{\text{dist, orbital}} \cong U_{L = 2l} \otimes W_{\Gamma = \text{Triv}} \oplus U_{L = 2l - 1} \otimes W_{\Gamma = \text{Alt}} \oplus \cdots \oplus U_{L = 0} \otimes W_{\Gamma 
= \text{Triv}}$ and $\mathcal H^{\text{dist, spin}} \cong V_{S=1} \otimes W_{\Gamma = \text{Triv}} \oplus W_{S=0} \otimes W_{\Gamma = \text{Alt}} $.

Comment: Using $W_{\Gamma = \text{Triv}} \otimes W_{\Gamma = \text{Triv}} \cong W_{\Gamma = \text{Alt}} \otimes W_{\Gamma = \text{Alt}} \cong W_{\Gamma = \text{Triv}}$ and $W_{\Gamma = \text{Triv}} \otimes W_{\Gamma = \text{Alt}} \cong W_{\Gamma = \text{Alt}}$, you can obtain a decomposition for $\mathcal H^{\text{dist}} \cong \mathcal H^{\text{dist, orbital}} \otimes \mathcal H^{\text{dist, orbital}} $ in terms of irreps of $SO(3)_{\text{orbital}} \times SU(2)_{\text{spin}} \times \text{Sym}(N)$. In the $l = 1$ case, the result is as written in both of our answers (which agree with one other).

Comment: Notice that the $3$-particle case is more sophisticated than this, because $\text{Sym}(N)$ has _three_ irreps: the trivial $1$-dimensional irrep, the alternating $1$-dimensional irrep, and the standard $2$-dimensional irrep. When taking tensor products, you need to know that $W_{\Gamma = \text{Stand}} \otimes W_{\Gamma = \text{Stand}} \cong W_{\Gamma = \text{Triv}} \oplus W_{\Gamma = \text{Alt}} \oplus W_{\Gamma = \text{Stand}}$, which you can verify using character theory. So it's the same idea, but the calculation is more involved.